# What happens exactly when I type 'bash' on the Terminal command line on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

I have an alias that I've added to .bashrc, and it only activates in Terminal after I run the 'bash' command. I feel like I should know what's happening here, but I don't. :)

Comment: If your default shell isn't bash, then bash won't run until you explicitly execute it using the 'bash' command.  This would result in the behaviour you seem to experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of OS X you are using your default shell might not be bash.  You can verify this by typing(before you run 'bash'):

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

You can change your default shell to bash so you don't have to keep running the command by following the instructions here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/21044/how-do-i-change-a-users-default-shell-in-osx

From @chopper3

> for <=10.4 - netinfo manager, /users/whoever/shell
>
> for 10.5=> - SysPrefs, accounts, control-click on user, select
>   advanced options, edit login shell field.

To further answer your question, the .bashrc is only used by the bash shell.  If you want you can figure out what shell you are using and add the alias to the .tcshrc or .zshrc instead of changing everything to use bash.

More info on what a shell is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)

and bash specifically:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)

Answer (score 6):

From `man bash`:

> When  an interactive shell *that is not a login shell* is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

On OS X, all Terminal windows and tabs run login shells, which is equivalent to you running `bash --login` instead of `bash`. `~/.bashrc` is therefore ignored, unless explicitely `source`d from e.g. `~/.bash_profile`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, [...] it first reads and executes commands  from  the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

Just create `~/.bash_profile` if it doesn't exist, and add the following line:

```
. .bashrc
```

Then `.bashrc` will be loaded even for login sessions.

Answer (score 1):

The alias doesn't work *after* you run `bash` - it works *while* you're running `bash`.

Basically, `~/.bashrc` is a file that contains directives that are run by `bash` every time it's started. The default shell for all recent versions of Mac OS X is `bash`, so it's run every time you open a Terminal. `bash` does not, however, magically know to re-read its configuration files when you edit them, so the alias doesn't immediately work when you add it to `~/.bashrc`. What you do when you run `bash` in your existing shell is create another instance of `bash` (which *will* read the modified configuration file, because it's starting up). Note that your original instance of `bash` is still there, running behind the `bash` you ran manually. If you close the shell (with the `exit` command) you'll return to your original shell (if you close it, you'll get a "process completed" message from the terminal).

So, to get back to your problem: your alias won't work until `bash` re-reads its configuration. You can do this by starting `bash` again (either by creating another shell inside your existing shell by running `bash`, or by closing and opening your terminal) *or*, you can use the `source` command to get `bash` to re-read a file. So, after you've edited `~/.bashrc`, do `source ~/.bashrc` - alias working, no starting `bash` again.

Comment: `.bashrc` is *not* read every time bash is started.